# Why should I use a class struct instead of a dictionary?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I saw a class implementation which pretends to be struct:

```py
class struct(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

myStruct = struct(
    field0 = 42,
    field1 = 42
)
```

Why should I use this instead of a normal dictionary:

```py
myDict = dict(
   field0 = 42,
   field1 = 42
)
```

With the dictionary I can easly use `myDict['field2'] = 42` to extend the dictionary which is not possible with the class implementation.

So what is the reason to do it like above?

Comment: Huh?  You can just as easily do `myStruct.field2 = 42`.  Of course, the ability to stick random extra fields onto an object isn't necessarily a feature, that might be considered more of an indication that the object wasn't designed properly in the first place.

Comment: Oh I was a little bit unprecise at this point with ```myDict['field2'] = 42``` I could create a new entry based on a string, which is as I know not possible with the class struct

Comment: That's still possible - `setattr(myStruct, 'field2', 42)`.

Comment: Thanks that worked. It is a little bit unintuitive, but it works. I would accept an awnser

Comment: Is it maybe possible to overload the ```__setattr__``` function to achieve something similar what happens in the ```__init__```?